# Why is the word red a boolean variable?

Tags: rebol2, red

```
red>> red
== true
red>> type? red
== logic!
```

Just curious to know why is `red` a boolean variable?

(perhaps unrelated) Side note: `rebol` in REBOL 2.7 console is of type `object!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined in the `"Red base environment definitions"` file as

`Red: true    ;-- ultimate Truth ;-) (pre-defines Red word)`

https://github.com/red/red/blob/9c355efa76ac1b5c17a8cbf359c5d7ab05a6a013/environment/scalars.red#L13

This file contains other initial environment definitions such as:

```
escape:      #"^["
slash:       #"/"
sp: space:   #" "
...
```

As @kealist points out in the comment below, it serves a useful purpose:

It stops the `Red []` header in scripts from causing an error.

In Rebol, the `rebol` word is bound to the `system` object so I expect the Red will follow a similar approach.

Comment: It's there so not every script has an error (undefined word: Red) from the header

Answer (score 4):

This is no longer the case:

```
red>> red
== 255.0.0

red>> Red
== 255.0.0
```